# Problem with an output in beamer presentation

Tags: r, output, r-markdown

I have a problem with output of an R code in beamer_presentation with Markdown. One of my r code apart from a plot returns something like this:

```
## $title
## list()
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "waiver"##
...
```

My r code options are:
`{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height = 3, fig.width = 3}`

I've tried to remove it with a cache and message options. Other codes works normal so I'm really confused. I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi, we need more information to help you. Usually it is best to provide a self-contained minimal example that fully enables us to reproduce a problem on our machine. You really should do so from now on to get good help quickly. You may find help here: [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: taking a punt... have you forgotten to use `+` to connect the rest of your ggplot code to a line of code defining a title i,e, you just have `labs()` or `ggtitle()` but not `+ labs()`